# how to scroll horizantally inside smart tab layout?

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with smarttablayout. and I want to swipe to next page

when the webview scroll finishes.

I've searched, and find some solutions, but nothing I did resolve this issue.

Comment: Please improve your question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Um..https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout

Comment: sorry , it is best question